# linked tables and adding columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have data in ExcelSheet1.  I have another sheet, ExcelSheet2, that I want to have a reflection of some columns from Excelsheet1.  I made a linked table and everything displays correctly, with the data from Excelsheet1 spanning columns A:I in Exclesheet2.

But, I wanted to be able to add additional columns that I can type extra info into.  For example, in cell J2 I could add the text "this sales resulted in 50k profit".  But, if that sale (from the linked data in Excelsheet1) is deleted, my new entry in J2 is not deleted along with the row from the linked table, and slides down to the next sale from the linked table, so then my rows are out of whack.

I just want the new values/columns that I add in Excelsheet2 to be deleted alongside the linked table entries from Excelsheet1.

If my explanation isn't good, or if I can give other useful details to you, please let me know.  Thank you for your time

Using Excel 2013.

Comment: I believe I understand what you are describing. Would it be an option for you to add a column for comments in the source data? This would solve the problem if that is an option.

Comment: @Analyst123456789 Sadly, no.  I'm going to be rolling this out to 20+ excel sheets (each one representing an "Excelsheet2" from the example above, and each one will have customized columns after A:I where the linked data is from Excelsheet1.